# Unable to connect to Jenkins while install plugins

Tags: jenkins

I am unable to install suggest plugin, it is giving me unable to connect jenkins error.

I am using ubuntu 22.04 on ece
[image]

I tried to ping updates.jenkins.io and not able to connect.
I tried same thing in mac and in docker as well but not getting success

Comment: Try telnet and verify if updates.jenkins.io is actually accessible or not. `telnet updates.jenkins.io 443`

Comment: @RahulSharma I am able to connect with telnet, but how can i resolve the error that i am facing on plugin install, can you please help

Comment: please share logs of jenkins service.